# Windows Phone 7, does MouseLeftButtonDown translate to the deployed application?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, gesture, mouseleftbuttondown

Quick question -- if I code something to respond to "MouseLeftButtonDown" such as the pushing of an image, if I leave the code the same way when I ship the app, will this directly translate to the user pushing their finger down on the same spot, and thus fire the code?

Do I have to change the MouseLeftButtonDown to the gesture listener for this to translate, such that MouseLeftButtonDown is only used in place of non-touch monitors when coding to test things?

THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As corrected by Matt in the comments, the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event is not the same as an image tap. However, the result would be the same in that if your code works on the emulator, regarding the tapping, then it should work on the device.

You should try and get your app running on a device though as there can be things easily overlooked in the emulator. For example, performance can decrease on your phone since it's likely to be quite a lot less powerful than your PC. Therefore, if your app is performing fine on your PC (emulator), it doesn't  necessarily mean you'll get the same speeds on the device.

Comment: You're the man, KeyboardP. Would you happen to know a link to point me in the direction of being able to load the emulator app on my phone without going through the marketplace?

Comment: @topcoderwannabe - Afraid not :/ If you're a student, you can go via the Dreamspark program (https://www.dreamspark.com/products/Product.aspx?ProductId=28). This means you can release apps to the marketplace (not sure how many), but without paying the $99 fee. Also means you can deploy your app to your phone to test.

Comment: NO! MouseLeftButtonDown is not the equivalent of a finger tap! There are lots of subtle differences. This is most apparent if you're selecting items on a scrollable list. When you're finger makes contact to scroll the list the LeftMouseButtonDown is fired. This may make using your list impossible.

Comment: @Matt Lacey You're right, I stand corrected. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I feel a blog post coming on ;)

Comment: @Matt Lacey - I'd welcome it! :D I think I recall the listbox problem from the Backstage days now that you mentioned it.